# In Feynman functional integrals why do we integrate the action over all time?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, action, s-matrix-theory

Say the definition of a propagator in quantum field theory is:

$$G_F(x,y)=\int \phi(x)\phi(y) e^{i S[\phi] } D\phi$$

where $S$ is the action. Why do we integrate the Lagrangian density from $t=-\infty$ to $t=+\infty$ instead of from $x_0$ to $y_0$?

i.e.

$$S[\phi] = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}
{\cal{L}}(x,y,z,t)dxdydzdt$$

where $\cal{L}$ is the Lagrangian density. Surely we are interested only in the section between $t=x_0$ and $t=y_0$?

Answer (score 7):

Short answer (assuming proper time-ordering of $x$ and $y$):

$$
\langle \Omega| \phi(x) \phi(y) | \Omega\rangle =
  \frac{
    \langle 0 |
       U(-\infty, x^0) \phi_I(x) U(x^0, y^0)
       \phi_I(y) U(y^0, +\infty)
    |0 \rangle
  }{\langle 0 | U(-\infty, \infty) | 0 \rangle }
$$

These infinities has to be in the action integral too.

---

Now there is a rather deep reason for having time going to infinity in the path integral (the credit for this goes to Weinberg and his awesome [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521670535), as usual). The propagators usually has funny $i \epsilon$ in denominators, like:

$$
\frac{1}{q^2 + m^2 - i \epsilon}
$$

Which makes possible integration over $q$ and helps select proper pole with Residue theorem.

Although it is usually just assumed and omitted in calculation, this $i \epsilon$ comes from the phases of field at time $\pm \infty$:

$$
\langle \Omega,out|  \phi(\infty) \rangle \langle \phi(-\infty) | \Omega, in \rangle \propto e^{\epsilon \, \times \, \cdots \text{pairs of fields} }
$$

for some infinitesimal $\epsilon$.

(Note that in interacting theory it is possible to calculate this product of projections only at $t = \pm \infty$, because it is assumed that the theory is free at this time.)

Given that this product is proportional to the exponential form - the product of $\epsilon$ and pairs of fields will be merged with the action! This is the reason to have $\epsilon$ in the propagator.

(You may find more details in Chapter 9 of [Weinberg's QFT Volume 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521670535))

Comment: Thanks, its a bit too concise for me! The gist seems to be that you have to start with the vacuum in the distance past and future.

Comment: Elaborated on this. Hopefully you'll enjoy the answer.

Comment: @zooby That's right - the physical reason for this is that the vacuum state of an interacting theory is not the same as the vacuum state of the corresponding free theory.  They are *close* in the distant past and future, when the interacting "particles" are well-separated and the interaction terms are small, but they aren't identical.

Comment: In the context of Feynman diagrams, the difference between the interacting vacuum and the free vacuum is accounted for by discarding certain diagrams (e.g. the un-amputated ones) and adding various normalization factors - in other words, the LSZ reduction formula.

Comment: So is $G(x,y)$ not really the amplitude for a particle to get from x to y but the amplitude for a particle to come in from the distant past pass through x and y and leave to the distant future?

Comment: This is interesting interpretation! Usually it goes the other way around, though. You have to evolve vacuum from $-\infty$ where it is assumed to be equal to $|0 \rangle$ to the time where you apply operator. Interacting and non-interacting vacuums are different!

Answer (score 4):

This is a common theme in physics: If you have a separation of characteristic scales in the problem, physical effects associated with sub-dominant scales can be ignored.

E.g. in $S$-matrix theory, it is often assumed for simplicity, that the interactions can be neglected near the initial and final times, $t=t_i$ and $t=t_f$, and that the time interval $[t_i,t_f]$ is much bigger than all the characteristic time scales of the interactions.

In other words, if we are not interested in studying temporal boundary effects, we might as well send $t_i\to -\infty$ and $t_f\to \infty$ to simplify the problem.

Comment: And also (to be completely honest) this is the only regime where we know how to compute the $S$ operator perturbatively for an interacting QFT, right?